# Using Fabric8 to Deploy a Java Project

Tags: maven, docker, fabric8, fabric8-maven-plugin

I am trying to use Fabric8 to build an image for my Java application. However, I am new and this could be a duplicate question.

I have docker installed and the fabric8 library added via maven.

Below is my initial setup for the fabric maven plugin.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <dockerHost>/var/run/docker.sock</dockerHost>
                            <images>
                                <image>
                                    <alias>${project.artifactId}</alias>
                                    <name></name>
                                    <build>
                                        <from>java:8</from>
                                        <maintainer>${project.maintainer}</maintainer>
                                        <dockerFile>${project.basedir}/Dockerfile</dockerFile>
                                        <dockerHost>/var/run/docker.sock</dockerHost>
                                        <ports>
                                            <port>8080</port>
                                            <port>8081</port>
                                        </ports>
                                    </build>
                                </image>
                            </images>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Below is the error message I am getting.

```
Unable to parse configuration of mojo io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.30.0:build for parameter dockerHost: Cannot find 'dockerHost' in class io.fabric8.maven.docker.config.BuildImageConfiguration
```

Comment: From what I can see maven is unable to parse it. Maybe try adding `dockerHost` via quotes? Does it work when you pass it as a maven property `docker.host`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `dockerHost` element from the image build configuration. There is no such option for the [build configuration](https://dmp.fabric8.io/#config-image-build).

`dockerHost` specifies the connection to the Docker host, i.e the machine where the image is going to be built and eventually run. This option is not actually needed
unless the plugin cannot determine it by itself. The discovery sequence is detailed in the Global Configuration section of the [docs](https://dmp.fabric8.io/).

If you build with maven on the machine where the docker daemon runs, you normally don't need this configuration. The plugin will connect to the unix socket `/var/run/docker.sock` which is the default URL of the docker daemon.

If the requirement is to run the image on a remote host, then you either specify the `dockerHost` option or the `DOCKER_HOST` environment variable. On the host, the docker daemon must be configured for remote access.

I hope this helps.